# ElasticSearch how display all documents matching date range aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate, aggregation, elasticsearch-aggregation

Following elastic docs:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html

## Question:

How to make date range aggregation and display all documents that match to relevant date bucket just not the `doc_count`.

The Aggregation  :

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "articles_over_time" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "date",
                "interval" : "1M",
                "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd" 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Response:

```
        {
            "aggregations": {
                "articles_over_time": {
                    "buckets": [
                        {
                            "key_as_string": "2013-02-02",
                            "key": 1328140800000,
                            "doc_count": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "key_as_string": "2013-03-02",
                            "key": 1330646400000,
                            "doc_count": 2  //how display whole json ??
                 
                    [ .. Here i want to display 
                           all document with array based 
                           NOT only doc_count:2.......... ]

                        },
                        ...
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
```

Maybe I need to do some sub-aggregation or something else?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to perform `top_hits` sub-aggregation on `date-histogram` aggregation. All the options can be read from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html).

Your final aggregation would look like this

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "articles_over_time": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "date",
        "interval": "1M",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "documents": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like what Sumit says, however, I think what you really want is to create a filter with a date range:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-range-query.html#ranges-on-dates

That way you filter out documents not in the date range and only keep the right documents. Than you can do everything you want with the results.

Comment: Jettro Coenradie: Can filter give me an ability to map each document to their bucket range (for example .. 1st bucket: [1/1/2016/00:00 - 1/1/2016/01:00]--> {[all relevant  documents]..},...) , etc?

Comment: Ah, if you want to have multiple time ranges, than you need the tops hits answer from Sumit. The date histogram together with the top hits. Beware there is no way to do pagination with top hits. It is also not suitable to get all documents if there are to many of them.

Comment: Jettro Coenradie: Ohh..Yes, it is exactly my case i have a thousand of documents on each bucket, my final purpose is iterate over some fields on each document in the bucket and execute JDBC (external mysql db call) , so return value from db will map back to the document .. or to new document :)

Comment: Depending on the amount of buckets or time ranges I would think about using multiple queries. The top hits was created to create buckets and show a few of the tops hits.

Comment: I have 24 buckets(hourly per day) ,on each bucket thousands of mapping documents , so do you suggest using date histogram aggregation + multiple queries ? instead of "top hits" (I must iterate over all documents in the bucket in order to make db call per document) , is it possible to do with elasticsearch aggregation ? maybe using elastic script like "map-reduce"?

Comment: If you need 24 hours in a day and expect thousands of queries, I think I would take the overhead of 24 queries and not use top_hits but use a normal query. You could even create multiple threads each taking it's own hour.

Comment: Jettro Coenradie: Thanks